# Admob ads fails to load with status details Limited ad serving

Tags: android, ios, admob

Currently, my Admob apps for Android and IOS are under review. The status of the apps is `Getting ready` and the status details show `Limited ad serving Review in progress`.
[image]

When I search for `Limited ad serving` it means some ads are allowed for the app but my when the ads are loading its throwing following errors:

- Android: `Publisher data not found. <https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#9>`
- IOS: `Loading failed`

The app store data is already linked in the settings and pointing to the correct appstore pages.

Is this happening because my ads review is not complete yet? In that case `Limited ad serving` is very misleading status.

**Update:**
It's been 6 weeks since my app is under review. There are no changes in the review status or ads visibility. I have no clue how much longer this process can take. Is there any way to connect with the team to get updates on the review process?

Answer (score 2):

Your app is under review thus not ready to show ads. All new applications will face this from now. It'll be removed automatically after end of review process.
This serving limit applies to individual apps.
For example, one of your apps may be ready to show ads, while another one of your apps may not be ready to show ads.

Answer (score 1):

Admob usually limits serving ads for below mentioned reasons

1. Account being assessed
2. App not ready to show ads
3. Invalid traffic concerns

Looks like your account is being assessed.It will take few days (15 - 30 Days in some case more than that) before you get the approval.
Till then make sure you have placed the ads in your app as per the  [Admob Documentation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Your [publisher data](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#9&zippy=%2Cpublisher-data-not-found) is not correct which may be due to an incorrect ad unit id, the account is not properly set up or you are facing some policy issues. Follow [the steps provided by them](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#9&zippy=%2Cpublisher-data-not-found) if still, you are facing issue you should probably [get help](https://support.google.com/admob/gethelp) from the AdMob team but you have to wait after 4th January 2022 to get a reponse.